# Can gdb be made to break upon first entry to a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, gdb, breakpoints

Suppose in gdb I set a breakpoint on a function `foo` which is recursive.  Execution will then stop upon the first call to `foo`, and also upon every recursive call.  Is there a way to prevent the stopping on the recursive calls?  (I'm hoping for an "easy / straightforward" way that does not require code-specific things like setting more breakpoints that have actions to disable/enable the first breakpoint.)

Comment: How about something like `b foo if !$_caller_is("foo")`, see [$_caller_is docu](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html#index-_0024_005fcaller_005fis_002c-convenience-function).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  It's a little awkward.

```
define bypass
  disable $arg0
  finish
  enable $arg0
end
```

Suppose you have breakpoint 5 on a recursive function.  After hitting that breakpoint upon entry to the function, if you say `bypass 5` then the function will "finish," not stopping at all of its recursive calls -- and the breakpoint will be set for the next entry to the function.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I think that's only true for breakpoint `commands`, not for `define`.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging ssbssa's answer:

```
define rfbreak
  break $arg0 if !$_caller_is("$arg0")
end
document rfbreak
"Recursive function break": Set breakpoint at given FUNCTION,
with condition so execution does not stop upon recursive calls.
end
```

Note this only handles self-recursion, because `$_caller_is` only checks one stack frame up by default.  It can be configured to look up more than one frame.